# How to convert ASCII in x,y,z format using gdal_grid?

Tags: gdal, convert, dem, layers, esri-ascii-raster

I have a map saved in (AFAIK) Arc/Info ASCII format and I would like to convert it with [gdal grid](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) but I am getting errors.

My data (`p.csv`) is in the following format:

```
319053.25,319301.12,544.28
319074.57,319275.26,546.44
319075.00,319250.00,546.34
319075.00,319000.00,468.74
319075.00,318950.00,466.19
319075.00,318925.00,472.06
```

and I have a `p.vrt` written by myself:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="dem">
      <SrcDataSource>p.csv</SrcDataSource> 
      <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType> 
      <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="field_1" y="field_2" z="field_3"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

When I launch `gdal_grid` I get the following error :

```
$ gdal_grid -l dem p.vrt p.tiff
ERROR 1: Failed to find layer 'dem' on datasource 'p.csv'.
No point geometry found on layer dem, skipping.
```

Comment: I don't see any CRS definition in your workflow.

Comment: What can I do about it? How can I fix it? It's not even stated on [gdal_grid website](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html)

Comment: It is not the reason for the error, but you might get errors later on. `<LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS> `might solve it. But your coordinates are not WGS84 in this case.

Comment: Where can I find some information on this SRS (CRS) ?

Comment: See http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why, but if you rename your layer to "p", it works for me:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="p">
      <SrcDataSource>p.csv</SrcDataSource> 
      <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType> 
      <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="field_1" y="field_2" z="field_3"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

to be used with:

```
gdal_grid -l p p.vrt p.tiff
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I got an empty tiff :( what am I doing wrong? This are the results of `gdalinfo p.tiff`: [http://pastebin.com/wqYaajBU](http://pastebin.com/wqYaajBU)

Comment: I will post that in different question since this problem is resolved.